# Unable to publish a library which uses NLog to NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nlog

I'm trying to publish a C# library to NuGet using NuGet Package Explorer. The library uses NLog for logging. My local version works as expected.

I can successfully upload and then download the library, but when I attempt to use the version downloaded from NuGet I get a `NullReferenceException`. Further experimentation shows that this is caused by `LogManager.Configuration` being `null`.

Here is where I try to use `LogManager.Configuration`:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLibraryName");
var logTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget();
var loggingRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, logTarget);
logTarget.Layout = "${longdate} ${level} ${logger}: ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}";
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(loggingRule); // exception thrown here
```

It seems like my NLog.config file is being automatically used by my local version of my library, but not by the downloaded version.

In NuGet Package Explorer, my "Package contents" look like this:

```
- lib
  - net45
    - NLog.config
    - MyLibrary.dll
```

I have tried renaming NLog.config to nlog.dll.nlog, as recommended on the NLog wiki (https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file). This hasn't solved the problem.

What can I do to stop LogManager.Configuration from being null?

Comment: are you including the nlog.config file in your nuget manifest?

Answer (score 2):

First off, NLog is only going to look into *app.config* for its settings.  It won't look for a **.config** file named after the DLL. *(edit: this is the default behavior of .NET apps, but the wiki you referenced specifies other behaviors--I'll pass on whether or not they still support that, but I'll say the solution I provide below should always work)*

Secondly, you're adding the physical files to your package when you should be adding a *dependency* on NLog to the package.

To fix the first part, you'll have to specify some configuration file transformations in your pacakge.  The docs [can be found here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations).  Simply create a bare app.config file, rename it app.config.transform, then add all of the NLog specific parts to this file.  Include it in your package's content.

To fix the second part, remove the NLog dll from your content.  In the metadata for your package, add a dependency for NLog.  You can add it manually by editing the XML

```xml
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5">
        <dependency id="NLog" version="3.1.0.0" />
    </group>
</dependencies>
```

or by editing your package with the NuGet Package Explorer (easier, safer).  More info [can be found here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Dependencies).